# Why does my javascript pig-latin translator insert an extra comma?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, translation

I have a function for a pig-latin translator working except for when a word starts with a consonant cluster **(>1 consonants)**.

Here's my function:

```
function translatePigLatin(str) {
  var firstVowel = str.indexOf(str.match(/[aeiou]/));
  if (firstVowel===0){
    return str + "way";
  }
  else {
    var charArray = str.split("");
    return charArray.slice(firstVowel, str.length).join("") + charArray.slice(0, firstVowel) + "ay";
  }
}
```

`translatePigLatin("california")` should return "aliforniacay", and does.

`translatePigLatin("glove")` should return "oveglay", but it returns "oveg,lay".

Any ideas where the comma is coming from?

Comment: Missing `.join("")` from the second `.slice`

Comment: Hint: this happens because you're stringifying an array.

Comment: @robertklep  Is this the wrong approach?  What would be better?

Comment: The suggestion from @JJJ fixes your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you do that need to split the string into an array. Will the following meet your needs?:

```js
function translatePigLatin(str) {
  var firstVowel = str.indexOf(str.match(/[aeiou]/));
  return str.slice(firstVowel) + str.slice(0, firstVowel) + "ay";
}
console.log(translatePigLatin("california"))
console.log(translatePigLatin("glove"))
```

Comment: Yes, that's a better way of doing it

Answer (score 1):

Interestingly, the comma is coming from `array + "string"` operation.

```js
console.log([1,2] + "string") // Returns '1,2string'
```

In your case - you are not joining the second (`charArray.slice(0, firstVowel)`) array.